# keep different height boxes aligned in rows in large layout, stacked in small layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, I have four different content boxes whose heights I will not know in advance.  In large layouts, I want these four boxes laid out in a grid such that A is on top of B on the left half of the layout, and C is on top of D on the right half of the layout.  In smaller layouts, I want all four stacked on top of one another, A->B->C->D.  So I've got a basic bootstrap-3 grid (see [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mritty/unL42cav/1/)).

In the larger layout, I'd like for the top of Box D to be aligned with the top of Box B, again without knowing the height of any of the boxes in advance.  Obviously that would be easy in an old table layout, but I don't know how to do it with Bootstrap.  I could change it so that I have two `<div class="row">`, with A and C in the first row and B and D in the second, but then that would break my smaller layout, because I still want A on top of B on top of C on top of D.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer, given to me by a friend on Twitter, was to use CSS flex.  One `flex-row` with all four boxes, setting `flex-flow` to `row wrap`, and changing the `order` property for the smaller layout.

[Updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mritty/unL42cav/8/)